# Writing to a file in Python in a while loop

Tags: python, output, file-writing

I have a while loop which asks for user input to produce a new population. I want it to write the population to a text file every time the loop runs and replace what is already in there. I don't have much experience in reading and writing to a file. I was wondering if someone can help me correct this?

```
f = open('thesis.txt', 'w')
while True:
    x=input("\n\nhave you found your final individual (y/n)?")
    if x=='y':
        final=int(input("Which individual is your final one?"))
        print("your final individual is a dictionary as follows:")
        print(population[final-1])
        break;
    elif x=='n':
        print("\nto continue you need to select 2 of your favorie  designs.\n")
        report=[0,0]
        report[0]=int(input("the number of your first favorite design?"))
        report[1]=int(input("the number of your second favorite design?"))
        population=step(population,report)
        f.write(str(population))
        print("please copy and paste the following population in grasshopper.\n")
        print(population)
```

Comment: Why would you want to throw away the contents of the file until the last time the loop runs?

Comment: I am reading this text file from another program at the same time,so I need it to be updated everytime the loop runs. However , I guess I figured it out. I should open and close the file in the loop.

Comment: You aren't closing the file after you open it. You could move the `f = open('thesis.txt', 'w')` to where you actually use it, in this case, your `else` and after writing into it, closing it `f.close()` so everything saves

Comment: It's not clear what you want based on your code, can you convert it into pseudo-code maybe?

Comment: Better yet, use a `with` block.

Answer (score 0):

An implementation of something similar to this will work:

```
while True:
    x = input("\n\nhave you found your final individual (y/n)?")
    if x == 'y':
        # do stuff here
        break
    elif x == 'n':
        with open('thesis.txt', 'a') as file:
            # get further user input/do stuff here
            file.write('something\n')
```

The mode 'a' opens the file for appending so any data written to the file is automatically added to the end. The file will update after the logic in the with statement is complete.